# How to inspect code behind Swing GUI

Tags: java, swing, testing

I once had java app/plugin which allowed me to view the code behind any given Swing application panel. So while a Swing app is running right click on a section of the app and view the code for that section. What is the name of this plugin ?

Searches : 
https://www.google.com/search?q=java+swing+dev+tools&oq=java+swing+dev+tools&aqs=chrome..69i57.3189j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8

https://www.google.com/search?q=java+swing+dev+tools&oq=java+swing+dev+tools&aqs=chrome..69i57.3189j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8#q=java+swing+code+inspector

do not appear to return what I'm searching for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I'm looking for : "Swing Explorer" http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-swingtest/

Comment: @mKorbel what issues have you had ?

Comment: Swing Explorer seems to freeze, not sure if all Object are correctly colored